# How to we implement oauth2.0 flow in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a website that allows users to have accounts. Third party Developers can use oauth2.0 flow to get access to my users' accounts on my site.

I am building an iOS sdk allowing third party developers to implement oauth2.0 flow to get access to my users' accounts.

I was envisioning the following:

- User clicks button in iPhone app.
- Sees web view where they go to mysite.com/oauth2 (my website with the oauth2.0 flow page)
- Login/Signup then click on Grant Access (to grant developer access to their account on my site).
- Web view redirects to a url with a code
- Somehow the system uses that code to make an api call to my site to get an access token for that user so that the developer can then get access to that user's account. The thing is that the developer needs to make this API call with their application secret key, and I don't want the developer to store the application key in the app for security purposes.

There are two possibilities for the last step:

1. Webview redirects to developer's server. Developer Server gets code, makes api call to my server to get access token for user to be able to create an account for them, etc, and then redirects back to a url ("app://access_token:....) that the webview recognizes as a signal to close itself. iPhone app then retrieves the access token from that url.

or

1. Webview redirects to a random url after having user click on Grant Access. The code is in the url. Webview then recognizes that there is a code in the url. Closes itself after calling a delegate function in the parent view controller and passing that function the code. The parent view controller function then sends that code to the developer server that makes an api call to my server (with the code) to get an access token.

What is the best way to accomplish the above?

Comment: try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19148429/oauth-2-0-webview-ios-sdk?rq=1 hope it helps :)
---
edit
---
sorry didnt realise that this was for making a SDK. maybe it won't help that much. sorry!

Comment: Best way I think is to use a custom URL scheme. The app should add the scheme to the "known URL schemes" in the info.plist file. The server can use this URL with the custom scheme to send the code to the app. See: http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html You can store the code in the keychain, that is secure and how other OAuth SDK's work on iOS.

Comment: question: can I redirect to http://iosapp/ and just catch that redirection?